# Find marginal distribution of Y while knowing distribution of X and $Y|X$

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Assume that X is uniformly distributed on (0, 1) and that the conditional distribution of Y given $X = x$ is a binomial distribution with parameters $(n, x)$. Then we say that Y has a binomial distribution with fixed size n and random probability parameter.

I have to find the marginal distribution of Y.
So I have to use that:
$$P(Y=y)=\sum_{x=y}^{\infty}P(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x)$$
But when we have that X is uniformly distributed I think the sum becomes a integral so we get:
$$P(Y=y) =\int_0^1 \binom{n}{y} x^y(1-x)^{n-y}dx$$
But what to do next? I think maybe take the binomial coefficient out from the integral, but how then using this to find the marginal distribution of Y? Hope anyone can help me? Do I also have to use that Y has a binomial distribution with fixed size n and random probability parameter?

Comment: Cross-post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/553941/119261.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is correct. One can show that
$$\int_0^1 x^y (1-x)^{n-y} \, dx = \frac{y! (n-y)!}{(n+1)!},$$
see the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) or [order statistics of i.i.d. uniform random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution). Multiplying by $\binom{n}{y} = \frac{n!}{y! (n-y)!}$ and canceling gives a simple expression for $P(Y=y)$.